# pythonic quicksort. call stack exceeded

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, quicksort, array-algorithms

This is my attempted implementation of quicksort in python

However, I notice that I have a max call stack exceeded error, likely because the length of my collection never goes down.

When printing, I notice that my recursive call does not update the "end" variable

```
def swap(collection, index1, index2):
    temp = collection[index1]
    collection[index1] = collection[index2]
    collection[index2] = temp

def partition(collection, idx1, idx2):
    left = idx1
    right = idx2
    pivot = len(collection)//2

    while(left < right):

        while(collection[left] < collection[pivot]):
            left += 1

        while(collection[right] > collection[pivot]):
            right -= 1       

        if left < right:
            swap(collection, left, right)
            left +=1
            right -=1

    return left


def quickSort(collection, start, end):    
    #Check for base case        
    if len(collection) > 1:        
        index = partition(collection, start, end)        
        newIdx = index - 1        
        if start < newIdx:                        
            quickSort(collection, start, newIdx)

        if index < right: 
            quickSort(collection, index, end)


    return collection


array = [7,5, 10, 12, 3,2,9]

quickSort(array, 0, len(array) - 1)
print(array)
```

Comment: Two things that are obviously wrong: 1. your pivot might be bigger than idx2 which shouldn't happen. 2. in quickSort there is no variable named right.

Comment: great! any hint on where to look?

Comment: also: how would that result in a call stack problem?

Comment: If pivot > idx2 then you keep swapping variables that are both on the left side of the pivot. partition() will keep returning the same pivot and will be called forever until you hit the stack limit.

Comment: You include `index` in your right-hand partition. A useful way of debugging would be to insert `print(start, end)` as the first command inside `quickSort`. That should show you what's going on.

Comment: got it. thank you!